# Prevent Laravel from overriding primary key

Tags: join, laravel, primary-key

Ok, I'm having a problem derived from the fact that Laravel overrides the primary key (id) from my table (pages) when performing a Join. Is there a way to preserve the primary key from pages after the Join? I need those primary key values intact for another query.

Heres my table structure:

**langs** 
id (pk) —
name —
code

**pages**
id (pk) — 
parent_id (fk) —
lang_parent_id (fk) —

---

**MainPageInterface**

```
namespace Repositories\MainPage;

interface MainPageInterface {
  public function getAllMainPages($lang);
}
```

**MainPageRepository**

```
namespace Repositories\MainPage;

use Page;

class MainPageRepository implements MainPageInterface{

  public function getAllMainPages($lang)
  {
    $mainPage = Page::join('langs', 'langs.id', '=', 'pages.lang_parent_id')
            ->where('parent_id', null)
            ->where('code', '=', $lang)
            ->get();

    return $mainPage;
  }
}
```

**Controller**

```
use Repositories\CPage\CPageInterface;
use Repositories\MainPage\MainPageInterface;

class HomeController extends BaseController {

protected $cPage;
protected $mainPage;

  public function __construct(CPageInterface $cPage, MainPageInterface $mainPage)
  {
    $this->cPage = $cPage;
    $this->mainPage = $mainPage;
  }

  public function getPages($lang, $slug)
  {
    $cPage = $this->cPage->getCurrentPage($lang, $slug);

    $mainPages = $this->mainPage->getAllMainPages($lang);

    $allPages = $this->getAllPages($mainPages);

    return View::make('index')
    ->with('cPage', $cPage)
    ->with('mainPages', $mainPages)
    ->with('allPages', $allPages);
  }

  private function getAllPages($pages) {

    $allPages = array();

    foreach ($pages as $page) {
        $subArr = array();
        $subArr['title'] = $page->title;
        $subArr['slug'] = $page->slug;
        $subPages = Page::where('parent_id', '=', $page->id)
                    ->where('lang_parent_id', '=', $page->lang_parent_id)
                    ->get();

        if (!$subPages->isEmpty()) {
            $result = $this->getAllPages($subPages);

            $subArr['sub'] = $result;
        }

        $allPages[] = $subArr;
    }
    return $allPages;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I'm sorry my first 2 solutions didn't work.

I've did some research for making an alias.

Try:

```
$mainPage = Page::join('langs', 'langs.id', '=', 'pages.lang_parent_id')
            ->where('parent_id', null)
            ->where('code', '=', $lang)
            ->select('langs.*', 'pages.*')
            ->get(array('langs.id AS language_ID));
```

First you specify the data to be selected in the select function, and then you get the query with the get function, and specify your column renames there.

I've tried it with my data, and I get what i think you want.

Comment: Hi Dennis, I tried both 'as' and 'AS' but got an SQL syntax error in both cases.. =/

Comment: Can you post your error? I haven't tried it myself.

Comment: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as `language_id` = `pages`.`lang_parent_id` where `parent_id` is null and `code`' at line 1 (SQL: select * from `pages` inner join `langs` on `langs`.`id` as `language_id` = `pages`.`lang_parent_id` where `parent_id` is null and `code` = ?) (Bindings: array ( 0 => 'pt', ))

Comment: I have edited my answer, can you check it? I assumed that you have a `Lang` model.

Comment: Hi Dennis, I fell like your first answer should have worked. I don't immediatly see how to make your new suggestion usefull to me. I think I'm going to edit my question to show some context to the query. The $lang is a variable I'm retrieving from my uri's to check which translation of the page I need to fetch from the database, and I'm not really seeing the usefullness of that type of foreach loop on this object. At least in my use case.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. Yep! it worked! thanks Dennis